# How to edit a layout of an activity using java in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

For example, there is a `MainActivity.java` and an `activity_main.xml`.  Now I have a java tool class called `SetText.java`. How can I set text to a `TextView` in `activity_main.xml`?

Answer (score -1):

ToolClass:

```
public static void setText(TextView tv,String msg){
   tv.setText(msg)
}
```

Use it:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview)
ToolClass.setText(tv,"somethings")
```

Answer (score -1):

on create:

```
Textview Settime = findViewById(R.id.txtentertime);
Settime.setText("Write As You Want");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).